# how to convert a vb.net string into PCHAR?

Tags: c++, .net, vb.net

net application and a c++ dll

In my program I'm calling a function from the dll that requires 3 PCHAR parameters

```
Public Shared Function myfunction(ByVal dllname As String, ByVal gamename As String, ByVal dllpath As String)

End Function
```

But the dll is expecting PCHAR Parameters yet I don't see that as an option with vb.net?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you post the signature of the C/C++ method?

Comment: _declspec(dllexport)int myfunction(PCHAR dllname, PCHAR gamename, PCHAR dllpath)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the native function just reads the `String / PCHAR` values and doesn't attempt to modify them.  If so try the following

```
<DllImport("TheDllName")> _
Public Shared Function TheDllFunctionName( _
  <In> ByVal dllName As String, _
  <In> ByVal gameName As String, _
  <In> ByVal dllPath As String) As Integer

End Function
```

You will need to replace `DllName` with the name of the native DLL and `TheDllFunctionName` with the name of the C/C++ function